# Update via POST apresentando erro

Tags: mysqli

Boa noite, estou começando a utilizar o mysql e estou com um problema. 
Consigo acessar todas as informações do meu banco de dados fazendo consultas, inserindo dados e tudo mais, porém na hora de dar um update, estou com problemas.
Segue o código.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$Susername = "meuuser";
$Spassword = "minhasenha";
$dbName = "obanco";
//Make Connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $Susername, $Spassword, $dbName);
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;");
    // Post Score

    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $newscore = $_POST['scoreDB'];

    // Check if exists
    $namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username='" .$username. "';";

    $namecheck = mysqli_query($conn, $namecheckquery) or die ("2: Name check query failed");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) != 1)
    {
        echo "5: Either no user with name, or more than one";
        exit();
    }

    $updatequery = "UPDATE players SET score = '".$newscore."' WHERE username = '".$username."';";
    mysqli_query($con, $updatequery) or die ("7: Save query failed");

    echo "0";
?>
```

Até onde eu consegui entender, o meu código está correto, porém sempre apresenta erro no $updatequery.
Fiz testes para ver se o problema era a conexão, mas não foi, se era a entrada de dados, o programa está enviando os dados normais. 
[image: Envio dos dados]

Sempre apresenta o erro 7, eu já não sei o que fazer, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Mude o erro fixo para `or die(mysqli_error($db));` e adicione na sua pergunta o resultado disso

Comment: Não apareceu nada, a mensagem fica em branco.

Comment: Havia descrito errado. O código correto é `or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Mesma coisa, não retorna nada

Comment: Sorack, eu descobri o problema, na linha mysqli_query($con, $updatequery) or die ("7: Save query failed"); estava errado e eu não percebi, não é $con, é $conn.
Perdi 6 horas do meu dia por causa de um caractere kkkk

Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, desculpa o incomodo.

Answer (score 0):

Como boa prática evite concatenar string nos comandos SQL. Opte sempre em utilizar o prepare statement para manipular o banco de dados, dessa forma você evita possíveis ataques SQL Injection.

Dê uma lida na documentação sobre [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) e tente fazer algo assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username= ?;";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("s", $username);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$resultados = $result->num_rows;

$sql = "UPDATE players SET score = ? WHERE username = ?;";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param("ss", $newscore,$username);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
$resultados = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$statement->close();
```

Abraços e espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Washington, boa noite, eu agradeço a resposta, vou estudar sobre os statements.

Comment: @R.Gomes ótimo estudos e estamos por ai se precisar ;)
Ah, resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Bom dia, resolvido, obrigado novamente.